# Java Gson java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm sending a JSON object (A rather big JSON object) to a Java servlet, I then use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) to convert the JSON to an object. Though when I try and do so I get the following:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "May 1, 2008"

I essentially have two formats of dates in the JSON object I'm trying to parse, the second date format - the one that *seems* works - looks like this:

```
Jan 3, 1953 1:01:31 PM
```

The tough thing here though is that I can't edit the JSON that I'm sending through. Is there a way that I can modify the JSON server-side before trying to serialize it into an object with Gson?

**Update**

As requested here is my `Member` JSON (I simplified it just to take into account the relative properties, as the actual JSON object I have has sensitive data and contains a lot of un-related properties):

```
{
    "birthDate":"Jan 3, 1953 1:01:31 PM",
    "beneficiaries":[
        {
            "terminationDate":"May 1, 2008",
            "birthDate":"Jan 3, 1953",
            "joinDate":"May 1, 2008"
        },
        {
            "terminationDate":"May 1, 2008",
            "birthDate":"Jan 3, 1953",
            "joinDate":"May 1, 2008"
        }
    ]
}
```

My POJOs:

```
public class Member {

    private Date birthDate;
    private ArrayList<Beneficiary> beneficiaries;

    // Getters and Setters...

}

public class Beneficiary extends Member {

    private Date terminationDate;

    // Getters and Setters...

}
```

Comment: share your json and model class.

Comment: Yes you can modify JSOn what you received at server.

Comment: @Nitesh - Updated my question with the JSON and model classes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define the date format with GsonBuilder

> Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("your date pattern").create();

Comment: Will that then only format dates exclusively in that pattern? Since I have two formats. i.e. "Jan 3, 1953 1:01:31 PM" as well as "Jan 3, 1953".